# Sorting values after transpose of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1091 | 347 | 2164 |
| b | 208 | 284 | 27647 |
| c | 0 | 8126 | 22 |

After transposing

| 0 | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.091 | 208 | 0 |
| 2 | 347 | 284 | 8126 |
| 3 | 2161 | 27647 | 22 |

```
df=df.set_index(0)
print(df)
df = df.T
print(df)
df = df.sort_values(by=df.index, ascending=True)
print(df)
```

But I am getting an error like:

```
KeyError: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

I am trying to plot index values to a column but it should be in ascending order because index 3 refers new value but index 1 is an old value in the time range.

```
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df['a'])
fig.show()
```

Comment: would `df.sort_index()` work?

Comment: Why are you using `df=df.set_index(0)` @bazinga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `df.sort_values(by=df.index)`, use `df.sort_index`:

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      1     2      3
a  1091   347   2164
b   208   284  27647
c     0  8126     22
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the index if you cast it to str dtype with a list comprehension.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
 '1': {0: 1091, 1: 208, 2: 0},
 '2': {0: 347, 1: 284, 2: 8126},
 '3': {0: 2164, 1: 27647, 2: 22}})

df = df.T
df=df.set_index(0)
df.index = [str(x) for x in df.index]
df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

Output df:

```
        1       2
1091    208 0
2164    27647   22
347     284     8126
a       b       c
```

Answer (score 1):

i would prefer to sort by specific column. sort_index sorts by first column afaik.

```
df.sort_values('column name')
```